# How to deallocate/free memory in android game

Tags: android, performance, memory, memory-management

I created a 2d game for android using Bitmaps. After closing the game, android studio memory section shows that the memory is not de-allocated. So how can i de-allocate memory which is allocated for bitmaps.
I have a Bitmap array called `chopper` and i am initializing like

```
    chopper[0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.copter1);
    chopper[1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.copter2);
    chopper[2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.copter3);
```

So during closing the game i tried to free memory like

```
chopper[0]=null;
```

But it doesn't show free memory in android studio memory graph. Is it the way to free memory? If not how can i free the memory before closing the game.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Java, making a object null will not release the memory. The memory might be released by the garbage collector when the garbage collector runs next time if are no references to that object anywhere.


In your case, assuming you are using this array in a activity, close  all the resources that might be using this array in the `onDestroy()` method of your activity, and ensure there are no objects floating around that refers this object after the Activity is destroyed.

Comment: I know the concept u just said. But i am trying to force clear the memory before closing the game.Is there any code in java to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `bitmap.recycle()` API to actually free memory.
See official article about [bitmaps memory management](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Comment: I tried this but android studios memory map still shows that the memory isn't cleared.

Comment: Maybe yes because i initialized all my other objects to null while exiting the game.

Comment: Track memory allocations in Android Debug Monitor and see if where this memory actually allocated (ex. android.graphics.BitmapFactory)

Comment: This is the [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sEHRL.jpg) of memory still allocated after closing my game

Comment: Do you use any native C/C++ (.so files) libraries? From your screenshot looks like ByteBuffer use most of memory.

Comment: I am using pure java not c/c++ libraries and all i want to know how to free those memories using java.

Comment: You have to find out from where it come. There is a lot of tutorials how to do it. It's big topic.